# Good starting point for learning to create ASP.NET SOAP web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am currently in the planning process of developing an application that I would like to expose the data from across multiple platforms using SOAP/XML web services.

I am developing the application using asp.net 3.5. Any links or good tips for getting started would be great!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using asp.net 3.5, your best bet is to go with WCF to create your services.

Take a look at this SO post for good WCF References:

[WCF For the Totally Clueless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296040/wcf-for-the-totally-clueless)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft (and hopefully the majority of .NET developers) are pushing for more adoption of WCF  as opposed to old school ASMX style ASP.NET web services. You might want to consider exploring your options with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx).(Link is a beginner's guide)

Answer (score 2):

By all means, check out those beginner WCF resources!

There's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, I would recommend you have a look at the [Pluralsight screen casts on WCF](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/browselibrary.aspx?technology=WCF) - it's an excellent series going from "[Creating your first WCF service](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/howtovideo.aspx?a=aaron-skonnard&n=creating-your-first-wcf-service)" and "[Creating your first WCF client](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/howtovideo.aspx?a=aaron-skonnard&n=creating-your-first-wcf-client)" all the way to rather advanced topics. Aaron Skonnard very nicely explains everything in 10-15 minutes screencasts - highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

If you're into reading books than I can recommend:

Programming WCF Services:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DW2ldput788C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=&f=false

It's on Google books so you'll be able to read large chunks of it online which should get you a good taste of it.